# model selection in linear mixed models

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, fitting

I have a question about finding the fittest model (lmer).  What I've learned is to remove the non-significant terms from the full model until none of the terms can be removed. Then consider the high-order interaction again and remove non-significant terms. However, I noticed that when I do this, sometimes the model changes, for example, in one condition it will be **A+C+D+A:C+A:B:D**, in other conditions it will be **A+B+C+D+A:D**.  I searched online and someone suggested considering AIC. The AIC of the first one with 5 terms is **-37429.5** while the second one with 6 terms is **-37428.3**. So does it mean that the first one is better than the second even if the second has fewer terms? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If my answer was the one you were looking for or helped you in any way feel free to upvote the answer or select it as accepted. This helps other community members to have less doubt if the answer is a solution to the problem you described!

Comment: @mugdi Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables that are non-significant in one model might be influenced by other variables and therefore their significance level might be biased. There are several ways to handle variable selection. For linear regression one of the most common is LASSO regression and Ridge regression

In your case I would suggest you try to use ridge regression for variable selection and to handle the bias-variance-tradeoff. The latter is the problem, that you always have to make a compromise for your model between a low bias of the covariates and minimized residuals. Ridge regression supports in contrast to LASSO regression interaction terms and polynomial terms.

The formal definition of the ridge regression formula is :
$$\min _{\beta}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X} \beta)^{\top}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X} \beta)+\lambda\left(\beta^{\top} \beta-c\right)$$

So the objective of the latter algorithm is to minimize the equation w.r.t. $\beta$

A regularization term or Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$, is used to shift the diagonals of the moment matrix. The latter is used to store the polynomials of the covariates.

A possible way to deal with your problem would be the following :

First : Add all interaction terms and the n-th polynomials of each covariate to your dataset.

Second : Use cross-validation to optimize the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$

Third : Use the optimal $\lambda$ to perform a ridge regression on your data.

A detailed way how to do this in $R$ is explained here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020700/ridge-regression-with-glmnet-for-polynomial-and-interactions-terms